# Git won't pull changes from another branch?

Tags: git

EDIT:  I should have noted that these are changes which **should already have been merged** from the "integration" branch.   They somehow did not make it into that merge, and now Git won't add them because it insists the branch is "Already up-to-date".  Arrgh.

Git won't update my branch when I try to merge another branch into it.

This file's got differences in another branch, but when I try to merge that branch, Git tells me "Already up-to-date":

```
$ git diff --stat integration MyApp/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/flow/appInfo.jsp
 .../webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/flow/appInfo.jsp    | 54 ++++------------------
 1 file changed, 10 insertions(+), 44 deletions(-)

$ git merge integration
Already up-to-date.
```

I'm not really sure how this is possible - can anybody explain how this situation can happen?

Comment: Are you trying to merge a remote branch into a local one? The command you're giving would merge local branch 'integration' into whatever branch you're currently in (presumably the master branch).

Comment: Nope, this is all local.  Diff is showing the local branch and merge is as well.

Comment: Seems like `integration` is already merged in the current branch, but the current branch has other commits/changes present. That's why `git merge integration` doesn't do anything, but `git diff` shows a difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you ask git to merge, it decides what to do based on the *shape of the history between the branches*. Since git is reporting that it's already up to date, `integration` must be an ancestor of `HEAD`. You can investigate how this came to be by looking at the output of:

```
git log --oneline --graph --decorate integration HEAD
```

If you'd like to **replace** your local version of that file with the one from the `integration` branch, you can do a single-file checkout:

```
git checkout integration -- MyApp/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/flow/appInfo.jsp
```

Alternatively, you can do a patch-checkout to view each diff chunk individually and decided whether or not to apply it:

```
git checkout -p integration -- MyApp/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/flow/appInfo.jsp
```

Comment: By "the shape of the history," I meant: If there are new commits on integration and new commits on HEAD, a proper merge will happen. If there are only new commits on integration, a "fast-forward" merge happens. If there are only new commits on HEAD (which it sounds like the case is for you), there's nothing to merge.

Comment: I'm bewildered by this - yes, the integration branch was just merged, but these changes should have come over with the merge!  The merge with integration was the previous commit.   Seems wrong that this file (and God knows how many others) weren't merged correctly.

Comment: You can see the full diff (from both sides) of a merge commit with `git show -m <sha of merge commit>` to see what else was done during the merge itself. Were there conflicts to resolve? Had HEAD touched `appInfo.jsp` as well? Were the changes to `appInfo.jsp` that you care about done since the point at which you branched off from `integration`?

Comment: I think I must have done something wrong on the initial merge.   I've deleted my branch and started over (branching from integration this time), and things seem to be working better.   I'll see how far I get.   Thanks for your help (and patience.)