# Pulling from another remote branch gives 'already up to date' message

Tags: git, git-merge, git-pull

My issue is somewhat similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20223881/git-wont-pull-changes-from-another-branch). I have a `feature` and `integration` branch on local and remote. I have done my changes on the `local feature` branch and pushed them to `remote feature` branch. Now i want to pull latest changes from `remote integration` branch to my `local feature` branch. There are many files which have changed on `remote integration` branch. When i run the command `git pull origin integration` from my `local feature` branch, i get the message:

> Already up to date

When i run the command `git diff --stat integration FileA`, i get this message:

```
.../com/pack/FileA       | 66 +++++++++++++++-------
1 file changed, 45 insertions(+), 21 deletions(-)
```

There are many commits on the `integration` branch and it will be very tedious to go and see each commit's difference, compare then merge.

How can i resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

**Try these commands:**

First Take fetch from remote.

`git fetch`

And then,

`git rebase origin/integration`

**or**

`git pull origin/integration`

Before rebase or pull first commit your changes or stash them, if you found any conflict resolve them.

Comment: I tried git pull origin/integration. That didn't work. I don't have any local changes hence, i think no need to stash my changes. Do i need to rebase ?